# Azure AD B2C: Extract single item from Json Array

Tags: azure, transformation, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to extract a single email address from an array of email addresses (stored in the otherEmails attribute).  I thought I could use the [GetSingleValueFromJsonArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/json-transformations#getsinglevaluefromjsonarray) claims transformation.  But, I get the following error:

> The InputClaims mismatched in ClaimsTransformation with id
>   "GetEmailFromJson" with TransformationMethod
>   "GetSingleValueFromJsonArray". The following InputClaims were declared
>   in the Policy but were not expected by the TransformMethod:
>   [StringCollection]inputJsonClaim. The following InputClaims were
>   expected by the TransformMethod but were not declared in the Policy:
>   [String]inputJsonClaim.

It's complaining that my input is a collection of strings -which it is.  The error says it wants a 'string' as input.  The documentation also states that it wants a string.  But then I'm confused how this should ever work with an array, as the name implies.

Essentially, I just want to return the email address in the id_token when using OpenID Connect.  But with B2C it seems I can't set the mail field and it's null when I query for it.  So, I've taken to using the otherEmails field.  But I really only plan on storing a single email in it.  Thus, I want to return the email claim as a single value claim, and not an array.

#### Update

After a bit more digging, I realized I can accomplish my goal without using a ClaimsTransformation.  I can just map the 'signInNames.emailAddress' to 'email'.

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="email"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [the **GetSingleItemFromStringCollection** claims transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/stringcollection-transformations#getsingleitemfromstringcollection) to get the first item in the string collection.

Comment: Ahh, of course.  I don't have JSON. I already have an array object.  And the example is of the field what I want to use.  Thanks!